Reading data from SQL Server with EF AsSplitQuery causes data to disappear (if writing simultaneously)
We have a .NET 7 application, that uses SQL Server and EF 7.
We have a memory cache that we read a large part of the database into (An "Item"-table with ~20 Includes), and refresh at regular intervals.
Because of the many includes, we need to use .UseSplitQuery() or the cartesian explosion would eat up all memory, causing the query to eventually fail.
This setup has worked fine for many years.
The last few months we've had a problem that this read operation might return objects with missing data.
But it's only one to many-relationships, on the many-side that fail, and only if we update or insert an item at the same time.
There are no exceptions thrown.
It appears regardless of whether I use Azure SQL Server or a locally hosted one.
Most commonly it's the item that has been updated that gets delivered without for instance "Multimedia"-rows. But it can also cut off so almost no of the items gets any "Multimedia" rows.
And it it fails at multimedia, all other one-to-many relationships after that will loose all their data for all items.
So let's say we have this code:
IQueryable<Item> lItems = Ctx.Item
    .Include(b => b.Multimedia)
    .Include(b => b.ItemContact).ThenInclude(bk => bk.Contact)
    .Include(b => b.Subtypes)
    .Include(b => b.EnvironmentalCertificates)
...

if it fails halfway through reading ItemContact, then all Subtypes and EnvironmentalCertificates will be empty as well.
All changes are written to the DB using a single SaveChanges(), which means it should all be done in a single transaction.
Any idea what might be causing this, or what I might test? I'm starting to run out of ideas.
We've tried:

Calling different SQL Servers (Both local and Azure)
Downgrading to .NET / EF 6
Upgrading to .NET / EF 8
Extra transactions around the insert/update operations (in case EF:s SaveChanges didn't properly protect it)
Removing all but one include
and lots and lots of other things.

For now, the problem has been patched by writing an "insanity detector" that notices if it suddenly looses alot of one-to-many-rows from one data fetch to another. But that's not really a "solution" to the problem.

EF core doesn't use transactions for Split Queries, so its possible that the view of the data between the individual queries will be inconsistent if you are also modify the collection. If you need to guarentee that the split queries will return a consistent snapshot whilt the data is under modification, you need to wrap the query call in a transaction, not the update.

Are you using a Snapshot or Serializable transaction around the select query? Any other type is liable to miss uncommitted rows, even if the other transaction has only committed part of its rows and part not.

Even serializable doesn't protect against inconsistencies (in SQL Server). Phantom reads (reading rows added/deleted/changed during the transaction but before a query first reads them) still occur. Only snapshot guarantees consistency during the transaction, but allowing snapshot isolation is a setting not to be applied without duly considering the consequences. You may as well move to Postgres :)

Yea, thanks for putting me on the right track. A transaction around the Select does indeed solve the problem.
Now I just need to make sure that the "cure" isn't worse than the disease - I.e. make sure that it still works while it's being hammered with multiple large selects with transactions, while at the same time being hammered with inserts/updates.

After quite a bit of testing, I have a bit more information about how to solve it.
As the comments above indicate, the standard transaction IsolationLevel (ReadComitted) isn't enough.
For me the problem disappeared if I used RepeatableRead, Serializable, or Snapshot around the read operation.
But then it came down to performance and stability.
Both RepeatableRead and Serializable uses locks, and this caused quite frequent deadlocks on the read operation whenever I was writing at the same time.
It also caused the timing of the write operations to become unstable. The write operations went from a pretty consistent 1-2 seconds, to some operations taking 20-40 seconds instead.
Then I tested Snapshot - and that seems like the prefect solution in this case.
With Snapshot, the data in the read operation was consistent.
Since Snapshot doesn't use locks, the deadlocks also disappeared.
The write times also returned to a consistent 1-2 seconds again, even under heavy load.
There might be some downsides to Snapshot that I haven't realized yet, but so far it looks like a perfect solution.
Once again, a huge thank you!
Without your help I would probably have been fumbling for a solution for a couple of weeks more.

In general I think that setting "Allow snapshot isolation" is a sensible thing to do. It changes how isolation levels are implemented drastically. In short: row versions (MVCC) instead of locks. In databases like Oracle and Postgres this is the standard architecture. The only thing is that now you can get optimistic concurrency conflicts that the database doesn't solve automatically. From a UX point of view, that's better than blocking transactions or deadlocks that the database doesn't solve either (or rather: causes), but for a conscientious developer it's quite demanding to deal with.

But all in all, I think it's one of the reasons why Postgres is gaining popularity because MVCC makes it so much easier to understand isolation levels and to reason about them.
